# Recursive sum in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to build a table of in-game item costs for the iOS game Builderment. I've entered the item recipes into a sheet named `Recipes`:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | **Gyroscope** | **Magnetic Field Generator** | **Quantum Entangler** | **Stabilizer** |
| 2 | **Gyroscope** |  |  |  | 2 |
| 3 | **Magnetic Field Generator** |  |  | 1 |  |
| 4 | **Quantum Entangler** |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | **Stabilizer** |  | 1 | 2 |  |

Each column is the quantity of items required to build the item at the top. (This is a small subset of the 53 items in the game, sufficient to illustrate the problem.)

1. A Gyroscope is free and built from nothing.
2. A Magnetic Field Generator is built from 1 Stabilizer.
3. A Quantum Entangler is built from 1 Magnetic Field Generator and 2 Stabilizers.
4. A Stabilizer is built from 2 Gyroscopes.

**Goal:** a second sheet `Costs` with the same table, where each column represents the total cost of building that item. Each cell is a recursive sum of the cost of each of this item’s ingredients.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | **Gyroscope** | **Magnetic Field Generator** | **Quantum Entangler** | **Stabilizer** |
| 2 | **Gyroscope** |  | 2 | 6 | 2 |
| 3 | **Magnetic Field Generator** |  |  | 1 |  |
| 4 | **Quantum Entangler** |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | **Stabilizer** |  | 1 | 3 |  |

The Quantum Entangler costs a total of 6 Gyroscopes, because the Magnetic Field Generator requires 2 of them, plus each of the 2 Stabilizers requires 2 more.

I manually entered this formula for cell D2:

```
=Recipes!D2 + Recipes!D3*C2 + Recipes!D5*E2
```

This is the sum of the pairwise products of this column (D) from the `Recipes` sheet with this row (2) of this (`Costs`) sheet.

I had to skip `Recipes!D4` because it will always be 0, and continuing the pattern would have resulted in `Recipes!D4*D2`, a circular reference back to this cell.

For cell D5 I entered:

```
=Recipes!D5 + Recipes!D2*B2 + Recipes!D3*C5
```

How can I generalize this to apply to the entire 53x53 table? It seems I need a `TRANSPOSE` somehow? To go down the column of the `Recipes` sheet while going across one row of the `Costs` sheet.

Comment: Is the "6" in the example Cost sheet correct? I'm having trouble following the logic a bit...on the recipies i see a 1 and a 2...1 plus 2 is 3; and 1 times 2 is 2.  not sure where the 6 comes from.

Comment: @WEBjuju yes it's correct, and explained in the first line following that table.

Comment: so, is it that the gyroscope is the base item and the stabilizer requires a quantum entangler to be created? are we counting the amount of total gyroscopes required for each one of the items? 

Also, is the cost before transformation taken into consideration? The quantum entangler requires 2 magnetic field generators and as such in reality it needs a total of 4 gyroscopes? If so, how do the cost correlates to the recipes? the whole row for gyroscope is empty on recipe except for 2 in the cell E2 so it does not seem to affect the results as much the result in the example in the way described.

Comment: You mentioned that "This is the sum of the pairwise products of this column (D) from the Recipes sheet with this row (2) of this (Costs) sheet." but the formula is

=Recipes!D2 + Recipes!D3*C2 + Recipes!D5*E2

Which is located in D2, the description makes me believe information in sheet cost is referencing both information in itself and recipe, could you please elaborate or provide a better example?

Comment: The number in cell Costs!D2 means: if I want to build 1 Quantum Entangler, how many Gyroscopes do I need to build first? The Quantum Entangler requires 1 Magnetic Field Generator and 2 Stabilizers first. The Magnetic Field Entangler requires 1 Stabilizer to be built first, so I need a total of 3 Stabilizers to build 1 Quantum Entangler (cell Costs!D5). Each of those 3 Stabilizers requires 2 Gyroscopes to be built. Therefore I need 6 Gyroscopes total (cell Costs!D2). @ReneOlivo I think you are reversing the rows and columns of the Recipes table; see the explanation just below it.

Comment: can you share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)?

Comment: @ztiaa I made one, does this link work? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FRRI5ysC-zXKXxELpgiQrYWgejJ6aHVKv3AuQg4U6L8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here's *[one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FRRI5ysC-zXKXxELpgiQrYWgejJ6aHVKv3AuQg4U6L8/edit#gid=1309620093)* for you to test it out:

```
=map($I2:$I,lambda(z_,if(z_="",,let(Γ,countif(let(item_,B1, row_,$A2:$A, col_,$A1:$E1, data_,$A2:$E,
     loop_,lambda(rec_,Λ,reduce(,sequence(rows(Λ)),lambda(a,c,tocol({a;if(counta(ifna(filter(data_,col_=index(Λ,c))))=0,index(Λ,c),
                 {index(Λ,c);rec_(rec_,tocol(map(row_,choosecols(data_,xmatch(index(Λ,c),col_)),lambda(a_,Σ,if(Σ="",,wraprows(a_,Σ,a_)))),1))})},1)))),
     Γ,loop_(loop_,item_),filter(Γ,isna(xmatch(Γ,item_)))),z_),if(Γ>0,Γ,)))))
```

[image]

Comment: The first row (Gyroscopes) appears to be correct, but when I copy/paste this row into the next row, it's all blank and the first row all goes to !REF

Comment: Its an arrayformula (in *Cell_J2* for example) and is auto applied to gyroscope, generator, entangler and so on. Incase you dragged it down its bound to throw an error.

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow. It seems to work for this small example, but like the other answer, it errors out when applied to the full 53x53 matrix. I made a new tab "Full Costs" to show the problem. (I believe I've faithfully translated your formula to work on an independent sheet instead of side-by-side tables)

Comment: yep 14 outta 54 columns were throwing *calculation limit reached* error. I cant think of any fix for this scenario right now. hopefully someone will pitch in with a different formula/script...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution.

`=MAP(B1:E1,LAMBDA(i,LET(l,TOCOL(A2:A,1),u,B1:E1,r,FILTER(Recipes!B2:E,A2:A<>""),d,REDUCE({l,FILTER(r,u=i)},SEQUENCE(COUNTA(l)^2),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;{l,FILTER(r*INDEX(a,c,2),u=INDEX(a,c,1))}})),q,UNIQUE(INDEX(d,,1)),MAP(q,LAMBDA(q,IFERROR(1/SUM(FILTER(INDEX(d,,2),q=INDEX(d,,1)))^-1))))))`

You can find this formula in tab 'z' cell B2.

Comment: It seems to work for the tiny example, but when I use it on the full 53x53 sheet I get an error: "Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula." :(

Comment: Try to change `^2` to `*2`.

Comment: Now I can't get it work at all...crashes Chrome ("Aw, snap! Error code: 5") with either ^2 or *2